# How can I stop Maven from automatically updating its local repository?

Tags: java, git, spring-boot, maven, visual-studio-code

I'm developing a Java-based application and using Maven to manage its packages with Visual Studio Code.

While coding, I have noticed that my git detects some slf4j files were automatically updated even though I did nothing about my code. The updated files are not actually libraries, but only Javadoc, sources, and some text files.

[image: The list of updated files]

I don't want them to update automatically but want to manually update them if needed.
What is the cause of this behavior and how can I suppress it?

I know I can stop Maven from updating dependent libraries when building my codes by attaching `-o` to a command, is there any similar ways?

Comment: First question: Where is your working directory? Have you changed the configuration `settings.xml` ?

Comment: Yes, I have configured `settings.xml` to manage libraries with git.

Comment: Please show your settings.xml file and what you have changed. And in which way do you manager your libraries with Git? Have you committed jar files?

Comment: I have added `<localRepository>C:\Workspace\...</localRepository>` line to the xml. I never modify/commit libraries but need to let them under git because of my company's policy.

Comment: First manually changing that does not make sense leave the conventions. What does that mean: `never modify/commit libraries but need to let them under git because of my company's policy.` ? If they are under git you commit if not under git they are not committed. They do not belong into the project you are working with. That's the reason having a local cache which is located in `$HOME/.m2/repository` ... If you have configured your local repository into your working area it's not astonishing that you can changes...

Comment: Don't put JARs into git. Talk to your boss about it if necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've modified the configuration file `settings.xml` to include the following section and now Maven no longer updates its local repository.

```xml
<profiles>
  <profile>
    <repositories>
      <repository>
        <id>repo1</id>
        <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/</url>
        <releases>
          <updatePolicy>Never</updatePolicy>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
          <updatePolicy>Never</updatePolicy>
        </snapshots>
      </repository>
    </repositories>
  </profile>
</profiles>
```

`repository` section is needed for all repos that are currently used. Even with this setting, Maven can download libraries if they don't exist in the local repository when building a package.